# MySql Replication in two directions

Tags: mysql, replication

I am successfully able to set up master-slave replication of database with MySQL. So, whenever I am updating my database on master, It will automatically replicated on the slave. Now, I have situation like, it is also possible that database might be updated on the slave, and it should be replicated on master. Basically, I want the Replication in two direction.

Please, suggest me some possible ways

Answer (score 1):

This is called as MySQL Master-Master replication.
You can follow these links which can be helpful to you:

[1. How to setup Master-Master replication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication)

[2. How to setup Master-Master replication](http://devel.reinikainen.net/40)

Another way to implement multi-master replication, including circular replication is using MySQL Cluster.

[3. MySQL Cluster replication - Multi Master](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html)